# Hibernate criteria query with join and where clause

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to write specific Hibernate criteria query using criteria builder. I want to get java code equivalent to following SQL query:

```
SELECT parent.pk FROM parent_entity parent JOIN child_entity child ON child.parententity_pk = parent.pk WHERE child.pk IN (?, ?, ?)
```

where (?, ?, ? ...) is a list of primary keys values of child_entity.

In my java code I use JPA entities (simplified version):

```
Class ParentEntity {
    long pk;
    // some business fields
    @OneToMany
    Set<ChildEntity> childEntities;
}
Class ChildEntity {
    long pk;
    // some business fields
    @ManyToOne
    ParentEntity parentEntity;

}
```

I've never used CriteriaBuilder so I don't even know how to start.